# Form Issue on cloning value of one input to other input with same name

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I have two inputs with same name in my form ( I use css to display one or the other depending of the screen size ), but on the form submition, is only gets the last one's value, which is a problem to me because is can be empty if I `display:none` it. I figured out a trick which consists of cloning the input value which is not empty to the other, so that when I send my POST variable to PHP, any one can return the value entered.

Here's my HTML code :

```
    <form id="form" class="form" name="postuler" method="post" action="receive-post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <div class="not-hidden">
           <label for="mail">Email address <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="ex: jdoe@exelcia-it.com" name="email" id="email" maxlength="40" />
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-fields">
           <label for="mail">Email address <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="ex: jdoe@exelcia-it.com" name="email" id="email" maxlength="40"/>
    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="upload" id="send" value="Submit" class="postu"/>
</form>
```

And here's my jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#envoyez').on('click', function () {
        if($.trim($('.hidden-fields #email').val())==0){
            $('.hidden-fields #email').val()==$.trim($('.not-hidden #email').val())
        } else if ($.trim($('.not-hidden #email').val())==0){
            $('.not-hidden #email').val()==$.trim($('.hidden-fields #email').val())
        }
    })
})
```

Here's my php code :

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
    var_dump($_POST['email']);
} else {
    echo "Theres a problem somewhere" ;
}
```

The problem that I get is that if I fill the `not-hidden` field, on the php side I get an empty string because it always retrieve the hidden-fields value.

Comment: Don't use input fields with the same name. display:none makes no difference to posted values.

Comment: Why don't you just give the inputs different names?  Then in your PHP code determine which one you want to use.

Comment: The reason why I want to do this is because the php side is not just only what i've put here, that was just a draft for debugging but I once gave them different names but couldn't get the job done on the php side ( I got errors at some points.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong in your jQuery code, such as:

- After triming the input text field's value, you're directly comparing it with `0`, which is wrong. Instead you should compare it's **length** with `0`.
- `$('... #email').val()==$.trim($...)`, `==` is for comparison and `=` is for assignment.

So your jQuery code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#envoyez').on('click', function () {
        if($.trim($('.hidden-fields #email').val()).length == 0){
            $('.hidden-fields #email').val($.trim($('.not-hidden #email').val()));
        } else if ($.trim($('.not-hidden #email').val()).length == 0){
            $('.not-hidden #email').val($.trim($('.hidden-fields #email').val()));
        }
    })
});
```

With the above snippet, it doesn't matter which input text field gets filled, the other field will also get updated with the same value automatically. And once you hit the submit button, you would get just one email id with the `POST` request.

**Another approach** would be to use `name` attribute as `name='email[]'` for both of your email input fields. There's no need to use any jQuery here.

```
<input type="email" class="email" placeholder="ex: jdoe@exelcia-it.com" name="email[]" id="email" maxlength="40" />   
<input type="email" class="email" placeholder="ex: jdoe@exelcia-it.com" name="email[]" id="email" maxlength="40"/>
```

This way, you can access the submitted email id(doesn't matter which input text field gets filled) in the following way,

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = array_values(array_filter($_POST['email']));
    if(count($email))
        echo $email[0];
    else
        echo "Theres a problem somewhere";
}
```

Comment: *"there's no element in your code whose id equals to envoyez"* -   Right; that's French for `id="send"`  ;-) Maybe they've taken that from a tutorial somewhere and forgot to translate it to their given language.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah, so that's the case. :-) OP must have forgotten to translate that in jQuery code.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking (happened).

Comment: thanks ! for the id "envoyez", actually mine was ok, I might have changed it in this post. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Ok thanks I used the jQuery part, that finally works !! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can try like this

```
       <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="ex: jdoe@exelcia-it.com" name="email[]" id="email" maxlength="40" />
       <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="ex: jdoe@exelcia-it.com" name="email[]" id="email" maxlength="40"/>
```

Then you can loop in the php script to check if the array is empty and get the populated key.

**UPDATE**

Here's how you can check the array and get the populated key

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $emails = $_POST['email'];

    foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {

        if (!is_null($email)) {

            echo $email;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is basic check you can save the email in variable or perform additional checks but this is the basic to get the value

Comment: Thanks, well, I can't figure out how to do this in php .. ? would you help ?

Comment: Check the answer .